# How to sort the original array passed to a function, Where we use the "Sorted( )" funtion inside the function. In Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to modify the original array using the sorted() function as I want the sort to happen in a specific manner using the key and lambda provided by the stored() function

```
    def sortED(a):
        a = sorted(a)

    def sort(a):
        a.sort()


    a = [3,2,1]
    sortED(a)
    print(a)

    sort(a)
    print(a)
```

output for the following is

[3,2,1]

[1,2,3]

Comment: If you can provide additional details about what exactly your objective is that will help.  Do you just want a function that sorts a? Or a function that sorts a in place?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the existing `sortED` function is that it creates a local variable `a` then `sorted(a)` is assigned to that local variable, but nothing is returned from the function.

If you return the result of `sorted(a)` then you can assign it to the original variable `a` and have a sorted list.

```py
def sortED(a):
    return sorted(a)

def sort(a):
    a.sort()


a = [3,2,1]
a = sortED(a)
print(a)

a = [3,2,1]
sort(a)
print(a)
```

```
Out: [1, 2, 3]
Out: [1, 2, 3]
```